# How to group numbers by predefined sum

Tags: shell, scripting

Data is in two columns (number and description):

```
1,item1
8,item2
4,item3
9,item4
```

The sum (using number column) is predefined 10 and input data should be ordered as close to that as possible (but not exceed it):

```
group1:
1,item1
9,item4

group2:
8,item2

group3:
4,item3
```

How to do it in shell script?

Comment: Did you do anything yourself? Do you have an algorithm? Why would two groups of 8 and 4 be closer to 10 than one group of 8 and 4?

Comment: This is the bin packing problem. This is an NP-hard problem to solve (i.e. not trivial). I wrote a few lines of `zsh` do do it for file sizes here: "[Group files into average size of the largest file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/484369)", but really, it's a bit outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Atm I have not write code yet. I'm thinking smb like first sort lines by number and then loop sum til 10 is reached and group1 is complete.. then next lines. Maybe someone knows some program that can already do that. @Tomasz 8 and 4 are not closer to 10 but you can't make any more groups ie. they would exceed 10 whitch is not allowed. Smaller groups are ok.

Comment: You should be able to take the code I linked to and modify it to fit your needs. It's currently getting filenames and file sizes, but you could change that to be your strings and numbers.

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda I'm looking it :)

Comment: Are 2 groups of 9 better or worse than a group of 8 and a group of 10? Is the input small enough so we can calculate all permutations ?

Comment: If col1 is 7 7 7 7 7 7 3 3 3 3 3 3, can output be 7 7 7 7 7 7 (3 3 3) (3 3 3), or does it have to be (7 3) (7 3) (7 3) (7 3) (7 3) (7 3) ?